# transforming jQuery code into Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, dojo

I have a problem with transforming my `jQuery` code into `Dojo 1.8` code:

jQuery code:

```
$(".someclass").css('left', 0);
```

And I get an error while trying to do this thing with Dojo:

```
domStyle.set(dojo.query(".collapse"), "left", 0);
```

It is said: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined` while if I query this class and print it into console I see 2 elements in it.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

`domStyle` can be used if have access to the node

```
domStyle.set(aDomNode, "left", 0);
```

`dojo.query(".collapse")` returns a NodeList.  The following should work:

```
require(["dojo/query"], function(query) {
    query(".collapse").style('left', 0);
});
```

Documentation around dojo's querying engine can be found here

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/NodeList-dom.html#dojo-nodelist-dom

---

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/zYH6S/

Comment: I use this and have following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLDivElement] has no method 'style'

Comment: collapse it is a list that contains 2 elements (images with id) in it.

Comment: /me seconds this answer. Problem is, `dojo.query(".collapse")` returns a NodeSet (dojo), not the single DOMNode (native). For full AMD compliance however, add `"dojo/NodeList-dom"` in `require` to assert having NodeList extended with css-capeabilities